# Stokes Theorem on manifolds with dense corners

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

I am currently working on a project, where I would (ideally) like to apply Stokes theorem on a Manifold with corners. I have found various sources, which justify this application. Except one thing:

In the book "Stokes's Theorem and Whitney Manifolds" by Anthony W. Knapp, on page 108, the author uses an indicator function $I_k(x)$ which is 1 on the subset $D(x,E)\geq2^{-k}$ and 0 elsewhere, where E is the set of "exceptional points" such as corners, and D is the distance function (exceptional points are the points on the boundary, which make the boundary non-differentiable). He later arrives at the conclusion, that, if E has the condition$$\operatorname*{lim}_{\delta\downarrow0}\;\delta^{-1}\vert\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{m}\mid D(x,E)\lt \delta\}=0,$$
then Stokes theorem $\int_{B-E}\omega=\int_{U}d\omega$ holds. The problem is that this proof doesn't work, if E is dense, due to the fact that the set of points which satisfies $D(x,E)\geq2^{-k}$ is empty. So, my question is: **Is Stokes theorem applicable on manifolds with dense corners (or better, with a dense set of exceptional points)?** If so, why/why not?

Comment: Does such a manifold with dense corners exist?

Comment: What does an "exceptional set" mean? The notion of "dense corners" is even less clear (I know what is a manifold with corners).

Comment: @MoisheKohan excuse the lack of clarification in my question, I will edit it accordingly. Exceptional set, defined as in the book mentioned above, is just a subset on the boundary, which makes the boundary "unfun" i.e. points where the boundary is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. corners, kinks). "Dense corners" means the situation, where the set of corners (or better, the exceptional set) is a dense subset of the boundary.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven there may be a hypothetical evolution of Cauchy surfaces which may, or may not fulfil such a condition. Our project is to generalize a theorem on all possible Cauchy surfaces, which includes such dense anomalies. (Technically it is not a manifold anymore, so you are right, but stokes theorem is still applicable to sets which are not manifolds)

Comment: I am not familiar with these notions. But have you read Jenny Harrison's [work](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9310231) on generalizing Stokes's Theorem or examined the detailed discussions in Federer's tôme on GMT in the setting of currents?

Comment: @TedShifrin What is GMT?

Comment: @FShrike Geometric Measure Theory. *The* source for technical material.

Comment: Are you willing to assume that the boundary is rectifiable?

Comment: @TedShifrin I have just read his paper, but due to my inexperience on this topic, two questions arose in my had after reading it: 1) On page 7, he uses "simplicial approximations" $A_k$ of manifold $M$ to define the integrals. Can every manifold be written as a limit of simplical chains?
2) On Theorem 3, he considers $(\lambda ,n)$-sets instead of manifolds, what exactly are these? Do they contain corners in our case? (Thank you very much for suggesting the paper and the book)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Not necessarily, but it would be still interesting to know it in the rectifiable case, I would be very thankful if you could suggest a paper about it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am retired and no longer have access to the paper. So I can’t help very easily.